# Daz bridge import, rigify error, eyeballs

Tags: rigify

Could someone please help. Using daztoblender bridge, I import daz character and then using the bridge in blender, select Rigify, the eyeballs end up pretty skewed.

Any solution, whats causing this issue?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix this issue, but I've heard the Daz to Blender bridge can be pretty buggy. You should try using Diffeomorphic (https://diffeomorphic.blogspot.com/p/daz-importer-version-16.html). It's a much better importer.